# Avoiding Prometheus call all instances of k8s service (only one, app-wide metrics collection)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I need to expose application-wide metrics for Prometheus collection from a Kubernetes application that is deployed with multiple instances, e.g. scaled by Horizontal Pod Autoscaler. 
The scrape point is exposed by every instance of the pod for fail-over purposes, however I do not want Prometheus to actually call the scrape endpoint on every pod's instance, only one instance at a time and failover to another instance only if necessary.

The statistics is application-wide, not per-pod instance, all instance endpoints report the same data, and calling them in parallel would serve no useful purpose and only increase a workload on the backend system that has to be queried for statistics. I do not want 30 calls to the backend (assuming the app is scaled up to 30 pods) where just one call would suffice.

I hoped that exposing the scrape endpoint as a k8s service (and annotating the service for scraping) should do the trick. However instead of going through the service proxy and let it route the request to one of the pods, Prometheus seems to be going directly to the instances behind the service, and to all of them, rather than only one at a time.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid Prometheus calling all the instances, and have it call only one?

The service is defined as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8worker-msvc
  labels:
    app: k8worker-msvc
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/path: '/metrics'
    prometheus.io/port: '3110'
spec:
  selector:
    app: k8worker
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3110
      targetPort: 3110
```

In case this is not possible, what are my options other than running leader election inside the app and reporting empty metrics data from non-leader instances?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3):

This implies the metrics are coming from some kind of backend database rather than a usual in-process exporter. Move the metrics endpoint to a new service connected to the same DB and only run one copy of it.

Comment: Another option is to have your leader pod tag itself in such a way that you can use that for a selector in a service. This leads to desyncs though.